# Comparação de categorias em campos repetidores ACF AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, taxonomia, wordpress

Fala pessoal, tudo beleza? Espero que sim! Eu estou com uma dificuldade em solucionar o seguinte problema. Tenho um **Post_type Chamado prêmio** e uma **taxonomia chamada vencedores**, no post tenho um **campo repetidor** onde cadastro vencedores, posso adicionar nome, logo, e a categoria (*ela é puxada conforme cadastro as categorias na minha taxonomia*), todos são campos do ACF! Além disso, tenho um select de anos e uma requisição ajax pra filtrar posts por ano, até ai tudo bem, porém na hora de listas os posts preciso listar todos os vencedores do campo repetidor **seguindo a regra que ele serão separados de acordo com sua categoria.**

Exemplo:
Vencedor 01 = nome: fulano de tal: logo = teste Categoria: Vendedor
Vencedor 02 = nome: fulano de tal: logo = teste Categoria: Vendedor
Vencedor 03 = nome: fulano de tal: logo = teste Categoria: Construtor
Vencedor 04 = nome: fulano de tal: logo = teste Categoria: Construtor

***Cada Vencedor com a mesma categoria precisa ficar em uma coluna html separada.**

Coluna 01
Vencedor 01
Vencedor 02

Coluna 02
Vencedor 03
Vencedor 04

Minha função ajax é essa aqui:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_rankings-filter', 'filter_rankings');
add_action('wp_ajax_rankings-filter', 'filter_rankings');
function filter_rankings()
{
    $html = '';

    $year = $_POST['ano'];
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'top_imobiliario',
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year'  => $year,
            ),
        ),

    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :

        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            $dateAno = get_the_date('Y');
            $vencedor = get_field('vencedores_do_premio');
            foreach ($vencedor as $vencedores) {
                $nome = $vencedores['nome_do_vencedor'];
                $logo = $vencedores['logo_do_vencedor'];
                $categoria = $vencedores['categoria_do_vencedor'];
                $html .= '<div class="single-vencedor col-md-4">';
                $html .= '<div class="bloco-img-vencedor">';
                $html .= '<img src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo vencedor">';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<h6>' . $nome  . '</h6>'; 
                $html .= '</div>';

            }

            wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile;

    else :

    endif;

    echo $html;
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce vai ter que organizar os seus vencedores por categorias primeiro... e depois devera organizar o seu html de acordo com a estrutura que voce deseja...

```
//Organiza os vencedores em categorias
foreach ($vencedor as $vencedores) {
    $vencedores_categorias[$vencedores['categoria_do_vencedor']][] = array(
        'nome' => $vencedores['nome_do_vencedor'],
        'logo' => $vencedores['logo_do_vencedor']
    );
}

//organiza o HTML
//loop categoria por categoria
foreach ($vencedores_categorias as $categoria => $vencedores_cat) {
    $html .= '<div class="categoria col-md-12"><h2>'.$categoria.'</h2>';
    //loop vencedor por vencedor da categoria
    foreach ($vencedores_cat as $vencedor_cat) {
        $html .= '<div class="single-vencedor col-md-4">';
        $html .= '<div class="bloco-img-vencedor">';
        $html .= '<img src="'.$vencedor_cat['logo'].'" alt="Logo vencedor">';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<h6>' . $vencedor_cat['nome']  . '</h6>'; 
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Maravilha cara, deu super certo. Muito obrigado